# Using Datasets in Mathematica 10.0

Tags: dataset, associations

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.1**

---

I am trying to use the *Dataset* functionality which was introduced in *Mathematica* 10.0 :

```
   dataset = Dataset[{
      <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {1}|>,
      <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {2, 3}|>,
      <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {3}|>,
      <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {4, 5}|>,
      <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {5, 6, 7}|>,
      <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {}|>}]
```

But this gives me an error as show in the image below:

[image]

I tried the same syntax in combination with

```
Needs["TypeSystem`"];
```

but with the same result. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. This dataset works well for me, no additional package is needed.

Comment: I can reproduce this on OS X. The error message is "An unknown box name (TypeSystem`TypeMap) was sent as the BoxForm for the expression. Check the format rules for the expression." After restarting the kernel it works again. But why did it stop working? That's a good question.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, after quit the kernel, the function works. SAnd I have the same issue with the assocation-function

Comment: I don't seem to have the problem in v10.0.0 under Windows.  There seem to be a lot of localized bugs in v10.0.0 -- hopefully a lot of them will be fixed in the next point release.

Comment: I ran this on OS X 10.6.8 and it worked perfectly. I had a fresh kernel.

Comment: A similar problem, if not exactly the same, is reported [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56381/142).

Comment: In OSX 10.8.5 and Mma v10.0.0 I can confirm this bug

Answer (score 2):

This bug has been fixed as of *Mathematica* 10.1.0.

The problem had to do with a conflict between the Suggestions Bar and the `Dataset` paclet code. The same issue has affected other functionality using autoloading in a similar way, for example `AssociationMap` as mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72039) or [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67388).

It is very likely, as [WReach](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/142/wreach) points out in a comment, that [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56381) is a manifestation of the same bug.