# Dataset: cannot reproduce a basic example. A bug?

Tags: bugs, associations

Just to report: 
I try to reproduce the very first example for the `Dataset` from the Documentation Center:

```
    dataset = Dataset[{
   <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {1}|>,
   <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {2, 3}|>,
   <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {3}|>,
   <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {4, 5}|>,
   <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {5, 6, 7}|>,
   <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {}|>}]
```

The message error reads:
An unknown box name (TypeSystem`TypeMap) was sent as the BoxForm for the expression. Check the format rules for the expression.

Comment: Seems to work fine on my installation; m10 on win7-64.  What version/OS are you using?

Comment: Works for me under Linux (both, directly evaluating the example in the docs and pasting this snippet)

Comment: Works for me Mma 10 on Mac OS X (10.9.4).

Comment: Alexi - have you tried copying your example back into a clean notebook with fresh kernel?  You may have a rogue invisible character in your code.

Comment: @ Ymareth Yes, It works after Quit/Start kernel. It would be interesting to understand, what happens?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem the user claims to be experiencing can not be reproduced.

Comment: I experience this problem intermittently, but have not yet been able to determine reproduction steps.  At some point in my session, this error begins to appear in all typeset Datasets, even the examples from the help.  In my case, a kernel restart usually corrects the condition.  V10.0.0 / Win7 / 64-bit

Comment: I also experienced the same issue. (V10.0.0 / Win7 / 64-bit ) This is how I can replicate it. association = 
 AssociationThread[{"A", "B", "C"}, {#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]]}] & /@ 
  RandomReal[1, {3, 3}];dataset = Dataset[association]

Comment: @PatoCriollo FYI, I couldn't find a way to make that expression fail on my machine.

Comment: @WReach Since you confirmed this problem, even if it is not easy to reproduce, don't you think this should be reopened?

Comment: @WReach please try as follows, in the first input cell do  association = AssociationThread[{"A", "B", "C"}, {#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]]}] & /@ RandomReal[1, {3, 3}] Then proceed to do shift-enter. Go to the next cell and enter the command dataset = Dataset[association] shift-enter and the error pops up. Tried in two different computers and the error appears.

Comment: Mr.Wizard I think now that it is indeed a problem, but not a problem of the Dataset function as I initially erroneously assumed. I met this problem also in other situations, when after some time Mma starts to give false reactions. Usually in such cases I think that I have left something in its memory that conflicts with the operation at hand and Quit/Start the Kernel. I did not do so this time, since it was the case that I have just started Mma, and the Dataset has been first I tried. So nothing at all should have been assigned as yet.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I was going to ask the same thing on chat, but I just now voted to re-open instead.

Comment: @PatoCriollo I followed those exact steps and they work for me.  I even tried it with no `init.m`.  Hopefully the next time the problem occurs for me it won't be in the middle of real work and I can take some time to diagnose.

Comment: This just happened to me while in the middle of a session. I opened a different *Mathematica* kernel and it worked fine while the other one continues to fail. This is strange.

Comment: A similar problem, if not exactly the same, is reported [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55196/142).