# AssociationMap loses definition

Tags: bugs, associations, predictive-interface

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.1.0.**

---

I'm facing a strange behavior of `AssociationMap`.

With a fresh Kernel session:

```
In[1]:= Definition@AssociationMap
Out[1]= Attributes[AssociationMap] = {Protected, ReadProtected}
```

After loading a package I'm developing, running some test against this package I *sometimes* end up with:

```
In[113]:= Definition@AssociationMap
Out[113]= Null
```

and **`AssociationMap` no more evaluate anything**.

I didn't ovveride intentionally `AssociationMap`, and, because it is `Protected`, I suppose I cannot have ovverride accidentally.

Any help is appreciated.

### UPDATE

After a lot of research I found the problem is related with the following minimal code.

```
Timing@<||>

AssociationMap[f, {a, b, c}]
```

The problem appear when putting the two expression in two different cells evaluating the two cells sequentially in a fresh Mathematica session. The problem doesn't appear if:

1. the two expression are evaluated at once, using "Evaluate Notebook" or putting the code in a single cell;
2. or one suppress the `Timing@`;
3. or one add another `AssociationMap` cell before the two and evaluate this new cell before the two others.

All tests done with Mathematica v10.0.1.0 under non-Admin account of Windows v8.1 x64.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### UPDATE 2

Wolfram Research confirmed this is a bug:

> Hi Andrea, Thanks a lot for sending us the feedback. This is indeed a
>   serious issue and I've filed an incidence report on that. I've added
>   your information to the report to make sure that you will be informed
>   for any updates on this topic. Many thanks again. Regards,
>
> [...] Wolfram Technology Engineer 
>   Wolfram Research, Inc.

Comment: The bugs tag is for confirmed bugs only, so you should wait for feedback from other users before tagging.

Comment: +1 for a well researched question. However I cannot reproduce your results. I'm using 10.0.0 on OS X though, so it could be local to your version/OS.

Comment: Sorry @YvesKlett

Comment: I tested for 10.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) and for Mac. I can't reproduce it.

Comment: I can't reproduce described behavior in v10.0.0.0 on Linux.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in v10.0.1 on Windows 7 (64-bit). Have you tried reinstalling *Mathematica*?

Comment: @SimonWoods unfortunately at present I cannot because I only have a slow connection and I didn't keep the installation media... But rally I cannot understand what happens. I'm also experiencing many kernel crash...

Comment: [Can't reproduce either](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YMckN.png), but: Have you modified *anything* within the Mathematica installation directory?  Do you have anything in your kernel `init.m` file?  Do you have the suggestion bar turned on?  What about auto-completion?  Can you post a screenshot of your [interface settings](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Fe0Tj.png)?  Do you have any other notebooks opened when you test this?  Do you have any palettes open?  Does it happen when running Mathematica without a front end?

Comment: Still unsolved on Mathematica 10.0.2 for Windows...

Comment: I encountered this feature...

Comment: Appears fixed in 10.1.0.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems I managed to reproduce the problem (M 10.0.1 or 10.0.2, OS X).  It appears only when the suggestions bar is turned on and I wait for it to appear after every single output.  This does appear to be a bug.

Workaround: turn off the suggestions bar.

Please do report this problem to `support` at `wolfram.com`.

[image]

The suggestions bar can be very useful for beginners, but it's been known to cause various problems in the past (many of those problems are already fixed).  If you don't use the suggestions bar anyway, consider turning it off.  The hint to the solution was that you mentioned that this doesn't happen either when the inputs are in the same cell *or* when you use Evaluate Notebook.  Both prevent the suggestions bar form trying to interpret the output of `Timing@<||>`.

Comment: Thanks for investigation. As a workaround, I forced an AssociationMap call at the very beginning of my code. Turning off suggestion bar instead apparently solved several unexpected kernel crashes occurring...

Answer (score 1):

This problem just started for me. AssociationMap was working last month in an existing notebook, now behaving as per report of OP. It exists in both 10.1 and 10.2 under Win7Pro64 (albeit I have both installed - maybe they share resources?). I had long ago turned off the suggestions bar. I have submitted a bug report to WRI. I have no special start-up (e.g. init.m), or customization config.

I have just identified a workaround: at beginning of Mathematica session, do:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
```

Comment: I flagged this post but I don't agree with myself anymore :P