# DeleteMissing issues

Tags: functions, bugs, predictive-interface

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.1.0.**

---

Has anyone had problems with the `DeleteMissing` function in *Mathematica* 10.0.2? I find that it rarely works. Most of the time it returns a list which still contains all of the missing elements. For example, let's say `a = {Missing[], 1, 2, 3}` then `DeleteMissing[a]` returns `{Missing[] , 1, 2, 3}`.

Comment: have not even used it so far, but have you seen und understood the level specification you can give as second argument? Without that it will drop elements at level 1 only, which might (or might not) be your problem...

Comment: Can you provide some code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @YvesKlett See my edit.

Comment: strange, I just tried this with 10.0.2 on Windows 7 and it seems to work (i.e. returns {1,2,3}). What system are you on?

Comment: @AlbertRetey I'm running OSX 10.7.5. Sometimes the function works fine, most of the time you get the output I've shown above.

Comment: I have now tried several times but could not see it fail. What exactly do you do between repetitions? Kernel quit, regenerate test-list, ... Can you explain where the lists you are trying with come from?

Comment: I've actually seen the problem when I open a new notebook, create a list with a missing element, then apply delete missing.

Comment: how exactly do you create such a list, by entering as input or is it returned from other functions? Can you show the offending lists when that happens with `InputForm`? One possible reason could be something like a `"Missing"[]` which as output will (with the default settings) look exactly like `Missing[]` but of course will not be matched by `DeleteMissing`...

Comment: When I create each list I check that the head of the element Missing[] is indeed Missing. Like above I'll just type List={Missing[],1,2,3} to create the list.

Comment: I can reproduce your problem with `DeleteMissing` in V10.0.2 running on OS X. `DeleteCases[a, _Missing]` works fine.

Comment: I *cannot* reproduce the problem on OS X, M10.0.2.  Do you have the suggestions bar turned on?  Have you tried restarting Mathematica?  Can you give a *complete* reproducible example?  I.e. show step by step what you did right after starting up Mathematica.  Make sure no other notebooks are open, just the one you're typing in.

Comment: [Like this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wu0ug9yxhza0t3e/Screenshot%202015-01-29%2015.16.10.png?dl=0).  Well, it must be the suggestions bar's doing as apparently now I can reproduce it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can reproduce this problem only if the Suggestions Bar is enabled.  In this case `DeleteMissing` seems to mysteriously lose its definition.

```
In[1]:= {$Version, $VersionNumber, $ReleaseNumber}
Out[1]= {"10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014)", 10., 2}

In[2]:= a = {Missing[], 1, 2, 3}
Out[2]= {Missing[], 1, 2, 3}

In[3]:= DeleteMissing[a]
Out[3]= DeleteMissing[{Missing[], 1, 2, 3}]

In[4]:= Definition@DeleteMissing
Out[4]= Definition[DeleteMissing]
```

This looks to be the exact same issue from here:

- [AssociationMap loses definition](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/67388/12)

Please report it to [Wolfram Support](http://www.wolfram.com/support/).

As a workaround, you can turn off the Suggestions Bar by going to Preferences -> Interface and unchecking Show Suggestions Bar After Last Output.  After turning off the Suggestions Bar, it is also necessary to `Quit` and relaunch the kernel for the problem to go away.

Comment: If you turn off the suggestions bar after you encountered the problem, you will also have to quit and relaunch the kernel.

Comment: @m_goldberg Thank you, updated the answer.

Comment: That and [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71889/excessive-memory-use-by-mathematica-kernel-in-10-0-2-after-executing-simple-comm). I guess I should really be shutting down that bar now.

Answer (score 3):

This is an extension to Szabolcs' answer. I would have explained it in 2nd comment  to his answer, but it is a little too complicated to be a comment.

There is another complication in regard to reproducing this problem. It is essential that the assignment

```
a = {Missing[], 1, 2, 3} ;
```

be evaluated before a `DeleteMissing` expression is successfully evaluated and the suggestion bar must up come at its completion.

Starting with a freshly loaded kernel, the suggestions bar enabled, and all the code in one cell.

```
a = {Missing[], 1, 2, 3} ;
DeleteMissing[a]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3}
> ```

will work.

Quitting from and restarting the kernel and making two separate cells.

```
a = {Missing[], 1, 2, 3} ; (* evaluate this cell first and separately *)

DeleteMissing[a]
```

> ```
> DeleteMissing[{Missing[], 1, 2, 3}]
> ```

reproduces the OP's problem exactly.