# Shadowing issue with DeleteDuplicatesBy

Tags: warning-messages, contexts

I have been running a function in *Mathematica* 10 with the command, `DeleteDuplicatesBy`. The function was working great until one day I started to get an error with the `DeleteDuplicatesBy` command. When I tried to run it, the command would turn red and say, "A symbol occurs in more than one context: One of the definitions is shadowed."

I have *Mathematica* 9 and 10 installed on my computer. I am not sure if that could be causing the error. Here is an image of the error in action.

[image: Error]

Comment: Does this persist on restarting the kernel?

Comment: yes it does, i am very confused as to what the problem could be

Comment: Which contexts does the symbol appear in? (Determine this with `Names["*\`DeleteDuplicatesBy"]`.)

Comment: the output is, {"DeleteDuplicatesBy"}

Comment: So it appears only in the `Global` context. Was the symbol appearing red there?

Comment: it was not red when using the Names function

Comment: That would explain it. Next time it goes red, could you run the `Names` code again?

Comment: Have you tried a simpler test such as `DeleteDuplicatesBy[{{a,y},{b,y},{c,z},{d,y}},Last]` before doing the more complicated example in your screen shot? Or is there a reason you posted the more complicated example? Maybe it would also help to know your OS.

Comment: @Jens I have tried a example like you've suggested and the command still shows up red. I am running OS X Yosemite

Comment: @Patrick Stevens , DeleteDuplicatesBy is still showing up as red, but not when I run it in the names command like you suggested earlier.

Comment: Please try evaluating `RebuildPacletData[]` and see if this fixed the issue.

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using (`{$VersionNumber, $ReleaseNumber}`)?  Try turning off the suggestions bar in Preferences, restart Mathematica, and try again.  I'm wondering if it is related to [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72779/12)

Comment: @Szabolcs I am running _Mathematica 10.1, 0_ I also turned off the suggestions bar in Preferences and it seems to have fixed my problem. Thank you.